# jQuery Show/Hide Not Firing Callback

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, animation

I have 4 boxes. Upon hovering over one of them, the other 3 are hidden and the hovered one is expanded. The expansion part is not happening, however, because my callback is not being fired!

**Code:** (Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CpKLk/5/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $("div#Content div").hover(function ()
                {
                    var toShow = $(this);

                    toShow.siblings().hide("swing", null, "slow", function ()
                    {
                        //Never gets here!
                        toShow.addClass("Expanded");
                        alert("Changing class!");
                    });
                }, function ()
                {
                    var toShow = $(this);

                    toShow.siblings().show("swing", null, "slow", function ()
                    {
                        //Never gets here!
                        toShow.removeClass("Expanded");
                        alert("Changing class!");
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            div#Content
            {
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            div#Content div
            {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            div#Content div#Box1
            {
                background-color: red;
            }

            div#Content div#Box2
            {
                background-color: blue;
            }

            div#Content div#Box3
            {
                background-color: green;
            }

            div#Content div#Box4
            {
                background-color: pink;
            }

            div#Content div.Expanded
            {
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Content">
            <div id="Box1"></div>
            <div id="Box2"></div>
            <div id="Box3"></div>
            <div id="Box4"></div>
        </div>​
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters that `.hide()` takes must be in this order: duration, easing, callback (http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Here is an updated jsFiddle for your example : http://jsfiddle.net/CpKLk/7/

The `.hide()` call is done like this:

```
hide("slow","swing", function (){ ... });
```

`.show()` must be called in the same way.

Comment: I'm using jQuery UI which overrides `hide`: http://api.jqueryui.com/hide/ Or is the documentation incorrect?

Comment: Although your suggestion does work which leads me to believe something is off with the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your script a little bit and came up with something like this:

```
$("div#Content div").hover(function () {
  var toShow = $(this);                      
  toShow.siblings().hide("slow").delay(10);
  toShow.addClass("Expanded");
}, function () {
  var toShow = $(this);
  toShow.siblings().show("slow").delay(10);
  toShow.removeClass("Expanded");
});​
```

Added the delay thing so it don't go crazy on mouse out and stuff.